# Error incomparable types: Object and int in Telegram

Tags: java, android, telegram

I imported the [Telegram](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) repository. and tried to run the project but got the above error in `Passcodeview.java` file.
It shows the error in this snippet

```
 @Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    View rootView = getRootView();
    int usableViewHeight = rootView.getHeight() - AndroidUtilities.statusBarHeight - AndroidUtilities.getViewInset(rootView);
    getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
    keyboardHeight = usableViewHeight - (rect.bottom - rect.top);

    if (UserConfig.passcodeType == 1 && (AndroidUtilities.isTablet() || getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)) {
        int t = 0;
        if (passwordFrameLayout.getTag() != 0) {
            t = (Integer) passwordFrameLayout.getTag();
        }
        LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) passwordFrameLayout.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.topMargin = t + layoutParams.height - keyboardHeight / 2 - (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 ? AndroidUtilities.statusBarHeight : 0);
        passwordFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
}
```

While the same project run once in my another machine properly, i did not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your other machine does not satisfy the condition

> `UserConfig.passcodeType == 1 && (AndroidUtilities.isTablet() || getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)`

So, the following "if" is never executed there:

> ```
> if (passwordFrameLayout.getTag() != 0) {
>             t = (Integer) passwordFrameLayout.getTag();
>         }
> ```

The problem is that you are indeed comparing an Object (the tag) to the number 0.

Change your code to

```
if (passwordFrameLayout.getTag() != null) {
            t = (Integer) passwordFrameLayout.getTag();
        }
```

if you are sure that the tag will always be an Integer if not null.

If you are not sure about that, use try-catch (NumberFormatException).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the line: `if (passwordFrameLayout.getTag() != 0) {`

`getTag()` returns an Object, which you can't compare to an integer constant. You should instead be checking that the tag isn't null. If you aren't sure that the tag will always be an `Integer`, you should probably check with `instanceof` too:

```
if (passwordFrameLayout.getTag() != null && passwordFrameLayout.getTag() instanceof Integer) {
```